# How to correctly extend class component in react typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to convert the current jsx code to typescript. The problem is with class component and extend it.

Example:

`export default class ViewComponent<P, S> extends React.Component<P & IViewComponentProps, S> {}`

`export default class UIComponent<P, S> extends ViewComponent<P & IUIComponentProps, S & IUIComponentState> {}`

`export default class BasePopover<P, S> extends UIComponent<IBasePopoverProps, IBasePopoverState> {}`

I am getting typescript error in UIComponent, whet I initialize this.state - TS2322: Type '{ hovered: false; focused: false; visible: true; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly.

I tried to change UIComponent to

`export default class UIComponent<P, S> extends ViewComponent<IUIComponentProps,IUIComponentState> {}`

and then I have error in BasePopover TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Readonly  & Readonly{ children?: ReactNode; }>'

This is example code on github: https://github.com/Husamoa/typescript-extends-component

How to correctly do this in react typescript?

Comment: *"TS2322: Type '{ hovered: false; focused: false; visible: true; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly..."* readonly ***what***? The rest of that error message was important. Please quote the entire thing, verbatim, marked up clearly as a quote.

Comment: It's worth noting in passing that the React developers actively promote using [composition over inheritance](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html).

Comment: propably related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39123667/react-typescript-extending-a-component-with-additional-properties